# Angular 14 valuechanges type error in visual studio code

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to use the new typed reactive forms from angular 14. And getting this error when upgrading angular from 12 -> 14.

I'm using typescript strict mode = true.

Im getting type error from visual studio code:

```
Argument of type 'string | { validators: ((control: AbstractControl<any, any>) => ValidationErrors | null)[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type '{ validators: ((control: AbstractControl<any, any>) => ValidationErrors | null)[]; }' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)
```

Creating a form with FormBuilder like this

```
  form = this.fb.nonNullable.group({
    country: ["", { validators: [Validators.required] }],
    area: ["", { validators: [Validators.required] }]
  });
```

Subscribing to valuechanges:

```
this.form.get('country')?.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
 checkCountry(value): <------ Gets type error here because checkCountry requires string in
});
```

How do i get rid of this problem i dont want to disable strict mode.
Is there any better of doing things.

Comment: it seems angular incorrectly infers the type of the control here. try simplifying the notation`country: ["", [Validators.required]]`

Answer (score 1):

The type emitted by `valueChanges` is a [union type](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/typescript-union), thus you need a [type guard](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-use-type-guards-typescript/) to be sure you're handling a string:

```
this.form.get('country')?.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
 if (typeof value === 'string') {
   checkCountry(value);
 }
});
```

Comment: So this is the new way to go now? because this was working in angular 12. Do I really need too check for all types like this.

Comment: `checkCountry(value||'')`